# Is IT possoble to check what embeded kafka topic contains?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka

As on the title, i wonder if i can chech what embeded kafka topic contains, just lile what local variable contains?

I tried in intelij debug gui but didnt find anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a KafkaConsumer to check data that any Kafka topic contains, embedded, or not.

Otherwise, you can download Kafka CLI tools, produce + flush some messages, then use `kafka-dump-log` tool on segment files written to disk, while your breakpoint is set.